# Error in program for Composite numbers

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am getting the following error in my program:

> int is not dereferenced

Can someone help?

```
public void fill() { 
    int b;

    for (b = 0; b < 400; b++) {
        if (b.isComposite() == true) { //Error-int is not dereferenced
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    arr[j][i] = b;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply `.isComposite()` to an integer because it can only be applied to an object. try this.....

```
for(int b = 0; b < 400; b++) {
        if (isComposite(b)) {
            //your other code
        }
}
```